# Creating a Managed Property using PowerShell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, managed-property

I created a Managed Property using the SharePoint 2013 UI, then I re-index and all works well.
Now I have been asked to create the same Managed Property using PowerShell script, but I have no idea where to begin.
I would be very glad if someone will show me some example.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a script from MSDN web site to create managed properties based on a CSV file:

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
      [String]  
      $SearchApplication 
)  

if ((gsnp Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){ 
    asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell 
} 

$objShell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application 
$folder = $objShell.BrowseForFolder(0,"Please select the folder containing your CSV file:",0) 
$pathfld = $folder.Self.Path 
$fullpath = Join-Path $pathfld "managed-properties.csv" 

$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $SearchApplication 

Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $fullpath | % { 

    switch ($_.Type){  
        "text" {$type = 1}  
        "integer" {$type = 2}  
        "decimal" {$type = 3} 
        "DateTime" {$type = 4} 
        "YesNo" {$type = 5} 
        "Binary" {$type = 6} 
        "Double" {$type = 7} 
        default {$type = 1} 
    } 

    if ((Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty $_.Name -SearchApplication $ssa -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){ 
        try { 
            New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name $_.Name -SearchApplication $ssa -Type $type -Retrievable:([bool]::Parse($_.Retrieve)) -Queryable:([bool]::Parse($_.Query)) -SafeForAnonymous:([bool]::Parse($_.Safe)) -EA Stop 

            $mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty $_.Name -SearchApplication $ssa  
            $mp.Searchable = [bool]::Parse($_.Search) 
            $mp.Refinable = [bool]::Parse($_.Refine) 
            $mp.Sortable = [bool]::Parse($_.Sort) 
            $mp.HasMultipleValues = [bool]::Parse($_.Multivalue) 
            $mp.Update() 

            $cps = ($_.Properties).split(",") 

            Write-Host "Managed property $($_.Name) successfully created." -ForegroundColor Green 

            foreach ($cpname in $cps){ 
                try { 
                    $cp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty $cpname -SearchApplication $ssa -EA Stop 

                    try { 
                        New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -SearchApplication $ssa -ManagedProperty $mp -CrawledProperty $cp 

                        Write-Host "Mapping between Managed property $($_.Name) and crawled property $($cp.Name) completed successfully." -ForegroundColor Green 
                    } catch { 
                        Write-Host "Unable to map managed property $($_.Name) and crawled property $($cp.Name). $($error[0].Exception.Message)." -ForegroundColor Magenta 
                    } 
                } catch { 
                    Write-Host "Crawled property $($cp.Name) not found. $($error[0].Exception.Message)." -ForegroundColor Magenta 
                } 
            } 
        } catch { 
            Write-Host "Unable to create managed property $($_.Name). $($error[0].Exception.Message)." -ForegroundColor Magenta 
        } 
    } else { 
        Write-Host "Managed property $($_.Name) already exists." -ForegroundColor DarkYellow 
    } 
}
```

The CSV file structure should be the following (First line defines the columns, by the way):

> ```
> Name;Properties;Type;Sort;Retrieve;Refine;Search;Multivalue;Query;Safe;Abstract;
> ows_Comments,ows_r_MTXT_Comments,ows_Abstract,ows_r_MTXT_Abstract;Text;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE
> Anno;ows_Anno,ows_taxId_Anno;Text;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE
> ```

You run the script as follows:

```
./create-managed-properties.ps1 -SearchApplication "Search Service Application"
```

Credit: MSDN

Comment: Thanks you for the help.  I get this exception: Import-Csv : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\create-managed-properties.ps1.ps1:17 char:1
+ Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $fullpath | % {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: Debug the script with PowerShell ISE. Put a breakpoint on line 15 and let me know what the `$fullpath` value is. Make sure your CSV file is named `managed-properties.csv`.

Comment: I get this: Set-PSBreakpoint : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\create-managed-properties.ps1' because it does not exist.