# Adding new managed properties with a script in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search

I was wondering does anyone know if there is a way to add a batch of managed properties in SharePoint Online? There is [PowerShell script for on 2013 for on prem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194639/creating-a-managed-property-using-powershell-script) but what about online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create new managed properties in SharePoint Online. You have 3 options though.

1. You edit one of managed properties provided by SharePoint Online. Their name has the format Refinable[Type][Number]. Just map the crawl properties you would like to use, and even add an Alias to them.
2. If you created some custom content types or columns, you can create some content and wait for SharePoint to create the properties for you. This happens when a full crawl is executed and that can happen after some hours.
3. Import an exported Search Configuration xml file. That can be done using a script. Check out [this](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html) post.

-Hope it helps.

Comment: I know you can import/export search configs, two things:
1.will the imported config overwrite existing one? The intention is just to add few managed properties and map them
2. config options in file are somewhat involved, need to some better examples.

If someone is looking at this there is a project on github:
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.SearchSettingsPortability

Comment: Hi @VictorShostak, yes the configuration file will overwrite existing settings. Any approach described above can be done programmatically, I was just outlining the options you have.